# Is this scenario allopatric or sympatric speciation?

Tags: evolution, terminology, mammals, speciation

I stumbled over a speciation scenario but I am not able to say to which type it belongs. I guess for people more familiar with the theory it might be easy to tell.

I was reading about the fin whale (*Balaenoptera physalus*). This species is usually devided into two distinct populations, a northern one (ssp. *physalus*) and a southern one (ssp. *quoyi*). During winter, the fin whale is going to more tropical regions to breed, while in summer to artic/antarctic regions to hunt. Now, since the seasons are opposite on the northern and southern hemisphere of earth, these two populations in principle never met in the wild.

Now, imagine these two populations survive the next thousands of years and that two destinct species develope out of this populations. Would this process be considered allopatric, or sympatric? I would tend to say allopatric, since the two populations are separated, but on the other hand, there is no literal barriere and in principle they are able to interchange...